# Backbone.js save() vs Jquery ajaxSubmit()

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js

When I execute model.save() in client side, I am getting null values in Spring framework controller. If I use Jquery ajaxSubmit() the values are received fine, how to achieve the same using model.save()

My Login model and view in client side code (Backbone used)

```
$.ready = function() {

    var LoginModel, LoginView;

    // Login Model
    LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        // URL to authenticate login.
        url: 'authenticate',


        // Ensure that each todo created has `title`.
        initialize: function() {
            console.log("LoginModel initialized");

            this.bind("change", this.attributesChanged);
        },

        validate: function(attrs) {
            console.log("LoginModel validate");
        },

        attributesChanged: function(){
            console.log("LoginModel attributesChanged");
        }

    });

    // Login View
    LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#loginform'),

        events: {
            "click #login-button": "performLogin",
            "change #login-username": "setUsername",
            "change #login-password": "setPassword"
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.username = $("#login-username");
            this.password = $("#login-password");
            this.loginButton = $("#login-button");
        },

        setUsername: function(e){
            this.model.set({username: this.username.val()});
            console.log("LoginView username set = " + this.username.val());
        },

        setPassword: function(e){
            this.model.set({password: this.password.val()});
            console.log("LoginView password set = " + this.password.val());
        },

        performLogin: function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            this.model.save();

            return false;
        }
    });

    var loginview = new LoginView({model: new LoginModel()});
}
```

HTML form

```
<form id="loginform" action="authenticate" method="POST">
    <div>
        User Name
        <input name="username" type="text" align="right" id="login-username">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Password
        <input name="password" type="password" align="right" id="login-password">
    </div>
<button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
```

Script tag working with $.ajaxForm

```
    $('#loginform').submit(function() {

        $(this).ajaxSubmit();

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: It's hard to say without more info ... can you post the code that's working with `"ajaxSubmit"`?

Comment: Now, I have added the working code both HTML and JS code, please help me.

Comment: I would look at the request on FireBug (or ChromeBug) genarated by model.save() and make sure all params are in there. You may wanna compare it to the request generated by ajaxSubmit() to see if you can see any differences.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [`jQuery form plugin`](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api), which I believe uses the JQuery `serialize` method, which converts the form parameters into a query string:

```
?username=name&password=pw
```

Contrast to Backbone, which serializes model data using `toJSON`:

```
{ username: name, password: pw }
```

So it seems you have two options:

1. Modify the Spring service so that it can accept JSON data
2. Override Backbone's [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) (or alternatively its serialize/deserialize methods `toJSON` and `parse`)

Assuming you go with (2), you can override the method in a single model, or globally by modifying the `Backbone.Model` prototype:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    if (method == "create" || method == "update") {
        var self = this;

        // get model in query-string format
        var q = _.keys(this.attributes).map(function(prop) {
            return prop + '=' + self[prop];
        }).join('&');
        // Post data to server
        $.post(this.url, _.extend(options, { data: q }) );
    }
}
```

Comment: @sokid sorry, I should have added an "untested" disclaimer.  I meant it as an approach, not as already-working code ...

Answer (score 0):

The below code works

```
    Backbone.Model.prototype.sync = function(method, model, options) {
        if (method == "create" || method == "update") {
            var self = this;

            var options = {
                           url: this.url,
                           type: 'POST',
                           success:    function() {
                               alert('Thanks for your comment!');
                           }
                       }; 

            // submit the form
            $(this.el).ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    };
```

In the last line, I have used $(this.el), here 'el' means the form id (selector).